# JSON datastore for categories in e-commerce site

Tags: javascript, json

I'm creating a sample json datastore for an ecommerce site. I'm not able to identify what the problem is in the code.
The JSON validator giving me this warning:

> Parse error on line 3:
>   ...category": "mobiles";
>         "lists":[
>   -----------------------^
>   Expecting 'EOF', '}', ':', ',', ']', got 'undefined'.

```
[
  {
     "category": "mobiles";
      "lists":[
       {
         "companyName" : "samsung";
         "modelName" : "s8+";
         "warranty" : "2 years";
         "price" : 45000;
       }, 
       {
         "companyName" : "samsung";
         "modelName" : "s8+";
         "warranty" : "2 years";
         "price" : 45000;
       },
       {
         "companyName" : "samsung";
         "modelName" : "s8+";
         "warranty" : "2 years";
         "price" : 45000;
       }
      ]
  },
  {
  "category": "books",
     "lists":[
       {
         "bookTag" : "java";
         "bookName" : "the complete reference";
         "authorName" : "herbert shildit";
         "edition" : "2016";
         "price" : 450;
       }, 
       {
         "bookTag" : "dataStructure";
         "bookName" : "getting started with data structure";
         "authorName" : "adam kooper";
         "edition" : "2017";
         "price" : 500;
       },
       {
         "bookTag" : "javascript";
         "bookName" : "javascript :novice to ninja";
         "authorName" : "herbert shildit";
         "edition" : "2016";
         "price" : 350;
       }
      ]
  },
  {
  "category": "shoes";
     "lists":[
       {
         "companyName" : "nike";
         "color" : "white";
         "type" : "casual";
         "price" : 4500;
       }, 
       {
         "companyName" : "adidas";
         "color" : "brown";
         "type" : "sports";
         "price" : 4300;
       },
       {
         "companyName" : "sparks";
         "color" : "blue";
         "type" : "sports";
         "price" : 3000;
       }
      ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Should be a comma instead of a semi-colon to separate properties

Answer (score 1):

```
     {
         "companyName" : "samsung";
         "modelName" : "s8+";
         "warranty" : "2 years";
         "price" : 45000;
       }
```

This is not a valid JSON. Consider using `,` instead of `;`

Instead your JSON should be:

```
  {
     "companyName" : "samsung",
     "modelName" : "s8+",
     "warranty" : "2 years",
     "price" : 45000
   }
```

Also, notice that the last entry does not have any separator at the end. So you should consider doing this for all your [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON).

Comment: There's no such thing as a JSON object.  It's just "JSON".